# How to build project with different environment in quasar

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I am using dotenv extention to setup different environment. How do i build project with staging and production config?

```
{
  "@quasar/dotenv": {
    "env_development": ".env.development",
    "env_staging": ".env.staging",
    "env_production": ".env.production",
    "common_root_object": "none",
    "create_env_files": true,
    "add_env_to_gitignore": false
  }
}
```

I have tried quasar build -end staging. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

There currently is a limitation in [quasarframework/app-extension-dotenv](https://github.com/quasarframework/app-extension-dotenv) which only supports `Production` and `Development` environments.

```
This app-extension can only handle 2 environments. If you need more environments, use the qenv app-extension.
https://github.com/quasarframework/app-extension-qenv
```

https://github.com/quasarframework/app-extension-dotenv/issues/21